# Ruby On rails: Using Rails Generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use `rails generate` to generate an integration test by running

```
rails generate integration_test static_pages
```

However, instead of invoking rspec and creating static_pages_spec.rb in the spec/requests directory it shows me this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:181:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :co
ntroller (ArgumentError)
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `normalize_options!'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:61:in `initialize'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `new'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `add_route'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1284:in `decomposed_match'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `block in match'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `each'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `match'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:507:in `map_method'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:469:in `get'
  from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in top (required)>'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
  from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.10/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
  from C:in `execute_if_updated' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1 0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in '
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `'
```

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Are you doing this from the root directory of the project?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The issue has been resolved. Can't pinpoint what exactly went wrong but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this exact same issue. I had typed `root` into my routes.rb file and forgot to add an argument. I see the same thing happens if I put `get` or `post` without any arguments.

Make sure to check your routes!